# Is it possible to have custom content types in big commerce?

Tags: bigcommerce

For a bigcommerce site I'm working on we will need to have custom content types or something similar that would accomplish the same goal.

One example is we need a way for the admin to arbitrarily add locations that have the following fields: latitude, longitude, as well as text fields for facts.

I saw that there were ways that you could add ui fields to products
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/configure-store-design-ui/defining-ui-options

But what I want to create is not a product. I want various types of posts with their own set of fields. Basically the same kind of features I would be able to find in something like Drupal.

Edit: Also I cannot use any outside cms. It can only be the bigcommerce cms alone

Comment: Can you be more specific? Custom types - on what? Custom blog posts? There is a way to get what you need with JavaScript but it’s difficult to tell what you need to do.

Comment: For example we plan on having an interactive map with locations across it. I want the admin to be able to click something like 'new location' or 'add location' just like they would a blog post or a product. And that location would appear as an interactive pin on that map. I can handle the JavaScript I just need an admin to be able to enter content.

Comment: That's not really something that you're going to get by just piggybacking on a standard BigCommerce theme. You'd need to develop a separate app with its own CMS and database, and your theme would read from that database to load the locations into your BigCommerce store and render out the interactive map. This isn't a built-in feature in BC - you can make it happen, but you'll probably need to build & deploy your own separate application to facilitate this.

Comment: An easier way would just be to use something like the Product Description / Blog Description / Category Description WYSIWYG editors and have some kind of structure where you can place HTML elements like <divs> that are loaded up with the data that you need - i.e. `<div class="custom-object" data-location="Maryland" data-longitude="48.001"></div>` - you can have a script read these in JS and render out your map, but it would be on a page-by-page basis. I really don't think you can edit this easily in BigCommerce alone, the system isn't set up for you to create arbitrary data entity in the CMS.

Comment: The issue with this is my ultimate goal is to allow the admin to add this content with touching any html or js but if that is not possible I understand.

Comment: Very possible, but takes a lot of work, you would need to build your own CMS - or your own embedded BigCommerce App, that would be available in the “My Apps” panel- it would be a big project.